# jQuery tabs inside modal

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I have a modal that opens when a user clicks one of two buttons. The button clicked should determine which tab will be open within the modal when it appears. The user should then be able to click back and forth between the two tabs and then click outside of the modal to close it.

I have this working *almost* the way it should, but I cannot quite get it all the way. Clicking either the login or register link will take the user to the correct tab at first, but if you close out of the modal, it will open back on the last tab that was open regardless of which link was clicked. How can I get the modal to open to the corresponding tab every time a link is clicked?

CodePen: https://codepen.io/m-use/pen/eEBxyv

HTML:

```
<p><a href="#" data-tab-id="tab1" class="form-modal-button">Login</a></p>
<p><a href="#" data-tab-id="tab2" class="form-modal-button">Register</a></p>

<div id="form-modal">
    <div class="modal">
        <input class="modal__tab-radio" type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked>
        <label class="modal__tab-label" for="tab1">Login</label>

        <input class="modal__tab-radio" type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
        <label class="modal__tab-label" for="tab2">Register</label>

        <div class="modal__panel" id="tab1-content">
            <p>Login form goes here</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal__panel" id="tab2-content">
            <p>Register form goes here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  var $modalButton = $('.form-modal-button'),
      $formModal = $('#form-modal').hide(),
      $modal = $('.modal');

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
      if (!$modal.is(e.target) && $modal.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $formModal.hide();
        $('html').css('overflow', 'auto');
      }
  });

  $modalButton.click(function(){
    $radio = 'input:radio[id=' + $(this).attr('data-tab-id') + ']';
    $($radio).attr('checked',true);
    $formModal.show();
    $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this code to open clicked modal everytime.

```
$modalButton.click(function(){
    $radio = 'input:radio[id=' + $(this).attr('data-tab-id') + ']';
    $($radio).prop('checked',true);
    $formModal.show();
    $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden'); 
});
```